# Convert line drawing into a shape with Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a simple bike outline and I am trying to figure out the best way to convert it into a shape. I would like the frame of the bike to be one piece or shape because currently, the frame is transparent as the spokes of the bike show through the bike frame itself which isn't what I want. That's why I thought making the frame one shape would help with that. Any suggestions welcome.

[image]

Comment: It's *really* difficult to provide help without understanding how things are currency constructed. Is that a vector drawing or a raster image? Are simply wanting to separate the (vector) pieces from one another or do you need to convert your raster image into vector pieces?

Comment: It's a vector image. I would like to separate everything and convert the different pieces into shapes.

Comment: What do you mean by "shapes"? Aren't they shapes already? Or is that merely a collection of disjointed lines?

Comment: The frame is all made up of paths

Answer (score 1):

To create a single shape from a collection of disjointed paths, you need to...

- Select all the paths which comprise the shape
- Choose `Object > Path > Join` from the menu 
  (you may need to do this more than once per "shape")

Another option is to use the **Live Paint Bucket** tool.

Select the artwork and then start clicking areas to fill them with color using the Live Paint Bucket Tool. When you are done. Click the `Expand` button on the Control bar across the top of the screen. You will be left with color shapes. At that point you can then delete any disjointed paths you no longer need.

Answer (score 0):

Scott’s answer is awesome and should work. Another option is to use “Pathfinder” which allows you to combine shapes or cut one from another. In this scenario you could put a fill on the bike frame parts, and take out the shapes that represent the space in-between the frame(the triangular sections in-between).

Just adding a fill to the shapes and messing around with “Object>Arrange” might give you the result you’re looking for.

It’s really hard to know what solution might be best for you without knowing how the shapes were made and what paths are connected.